# How to call the arraylist variable from one class to another class in android

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, hashmap

How do I call the `ArrayList` variable from one class to another class in android? I framed the `ArrayList` from Json Service, I have tried in many ways, but have a problem with how to call the array list from one class to another class. I using the following code to frame the array list with `HashMap`:

**Shown Below is FirstActivityCLass**

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {
                
                JSONObject e = null;
                System.out.println("In Background...");
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .detectAll().penaltyLog().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                String API = "http://traininglabs.com/nic/a-remainders-list.php?email="+email;
                System.out.println(API);
                JSONObject loginjson = JSONfunctions1.getJSONfromURL(API);
                responseArray=loginjson.getJSONArray("user");
                
                mylist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();                     

                JSONObject obj= responseArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    **String ss = obj.getString("id");
                    map.put("id", obj.getString("id"));**
                    map.put("state", obj.getString("status"));
                    map.put("entity", obj.getString("company"));
                    map.put("date", obj.getString("adate"));
                     s1 = e.getString("state");
                     s2 = e.getString("entity");
                     s3 = e.getString("date");
                    System.out.println("this is string--->" + ss);
                    mylist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error", "Error in API" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

This my Second Activity parameter of **ArryaList is id**

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            System.out.println("In Background...");
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll().penaltyLog().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            try {
                String ssp_state = sp_state.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String ssp_entity = sp_entity.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String ssp_date = sp_date.getText().toString();
                String ssp_time = sp_time.getText().toString();

                String API = "http://traininglabs.com/projects/nic/a-edit-remainder.php?id="+**id**+ "&email="+ mail_str+ "&sid="+ sp_id+ "entity="+ ssp_entity+datetime="+ ssp_date+ ssp_time;
                System.out.println(API);

                JSONArray loginjson = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(API);

                Log.d(TAG, "JSON_RES" + loginjson);

                return 0;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error", "Error in API" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
                return 1;

            } // return null;

        }
```

Comment: Create a singleton class which having arraylist as member variable and  add/read from any where..

Comment: You can use Global variables http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: @PankajKumar first class is get the values from the webservice, second class is update the the existing value. so only  was using two classes. Have any idea's.

Comment: Create a singleton class... or use Application class as vicky posted a link...

Comment: @PankajKumar sorry i don't know the  what is Singleton class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make it global, or put it into a singleton, more complex but persistent way as you are dealing with network share it via shared preferences.